# Show bipartite graph with $m=4$ and $n=4$ is not planar.

Tags: graph-theory

I need to show that the 4,4-bipartite $K_{4,4}$ graph is not planar. However, I don't have a clue on where to begin. I figured a constructive proof would suffice, but how can I be sure that that covers all the ways I can construct a 4,4 bipartite graph?

I can use Eulers formula, but since no three points are all connected in a bipartite graph I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Do you mean the complete bipartite graph $K_{4,4}$? What tools are you allowed to use? Presumably you can't use the fact that $K_{3,3}$ is nonplanar? Do you have Euler's formula and related inequalities?

Comment: @Casteels, yes I can use Euler's formula, but I don't see how it could be of any use since no three points are completely connected.

Comment: From Euler's formula, one can derive the inequality that any triangle-free planar graph satisfies $|E|\leq 2|V|-4.$